# put system.out.print in frame java [netbeans]

Tags: java, netbeans

first im newbie and not good in english
is it possible to put system.out.print in frame? let's say if i want to see all my output print in textfield or something like that.  i can put output print in textfield but it just settext one process. i want all log of my output in textfield, not just one output.
sorry if it dummy question,thanks for your answer before
i have code and i want to put all my output in text2(textfield)

```
   this is my whole code:



import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.swing.JTextPane;
import javax.swing.text.BadLocationException;
import javax.swing.text.Document;
import org.jpos.iso.BaseChannel;
import org.jpos.iso.ISOException;
import org.jpos.iso.ISOMsg;
import org.jpos.iso.ISOPackager;
import org.jpos.iso.ISORequestListener;
import org.jpos.iso.ISOServer;
import org.jpos.iso.ISOSource;
import org.jpos.iso.ServerChannel;
import org.jpos.iso.channel.ASCIIChannel;
import org.jpos.iso.packager.GenericPackager; 
import jpos.JPosServer;

public class server extends javax.swing.JFrame {


   public server() {
    initComponents();
}


    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">
    private void initComponents() {

    mulai = new javax.swing.JButton();
    text = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
    text1 = new javax.swing.JTextArea();
    jScrollPane1 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
    JTextPane = new javax.swing.JTextPane();

    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    getContentPane().setLayout(new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteLayout());

    mulai.setText("Star Server");
    mulai.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            mulaiActionPerformed(evt);
        }
      });
      getContentPane().add(mulai, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(129, 66, -1, -1));

      text1.setColumns(20);
      text1.setRows(5);
      text.setViewportView(text1);

      getContentPane().add(text, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(16, 96, 350, 130));

      jScrollPane1.setViewportView(JTextPane);

      getContentPane().add(jScrollPane1, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(50, 250, 330, 170));

    pack();
}// </editor-fold>




  private void log(String msg) {
    JTextPane guiConsole = new JTextPane();
  Document doc = guiConsole.getDocument();
  try {
      doc.insertString(doc.getLength(), msg + "\r\n", null);
   } catch (BadLocationException e) {}
  }



  private void setText2Text(String msg) {
  String toAppend = text1.getText();
  toAppend = toAppend + "/n" + msg;
  text1.setText(toAppend);
  }

private void mulaiActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    // TODO add your handling code here:

}






   public boolean process1(ISOSource isoSrc, ISOMsg isoMsg) {
   try {
         log("Server menerima koneksi dari ["+((BaseChannel)isoSrc).getSocket().getInetAddress().getHostAddress()+"]");

        if (isoMsg.getMTI().equalsIgnoreCase("1800")) {
                acceptNetworkMsg(isoSrc, isoMsg);
        }
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(JPosServer.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (ISOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(JPosServer.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    return false;
}

    private void acceptNetworkMsg(ISOSource isoSrc, ISOMsg isoMsg) throws ISOException, IOException {

      log("Accepting Network Management Request");

    ISOMsg reply = (ISOMsg) isoMsg.clone();
    reply.setMTI("1810");
    reply.set(39, "00");
    isoSrc.send(reply);
} 


/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String args[]) throws ISOException {

    String hostname = "localhost";
    int portNumber = 1234;

    // membuat sebuah packager
    ISOPackager packager = new GenericPackager("src/jpos/iso93ascii.xml");
    // membuat channel
    ServerChannel channel = new ASCIIChannel(hostname, portNumber, packager);
    // membuat server
    ISOServer server = new ISOServer(portNumber, channel, null);
    server.addISORequestListener(new JPosServer());
    new Thread(server).start();

    System.out.println("Server siap menerima koneksi pada port [" + portNumber+"]");


    /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
    //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
    /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
     * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
     */
    try {
        for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
            if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                break;
            }
        }
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(server.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(server.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(server.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(server.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    //</editor-fold>

    /* Create and display the form */
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new server().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}
// Variables declaration - do not modify
private javax.swing.JTextPane JTextPane;
private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
private javax.swing.JButton mulai;
private javax.swing.JScrollPane text;
private javax.swing.JTextArea text1;
// End of variables declaration
```

}

thanks for getting in my problem yogendra,i really appreciate it

Comment: If you want to redirect your output-logs printed with System.out.print(), you should take a look at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#setOut(java.io.PrintStream)

Comment: as i mention before,i just newbie and not good in english, i don't get it without example

Answer (score 0):

before each text2.setText(), you can get the text first, then append the new string in the original string.

```
String toAppend = text2.getText();
toAppend = toAppend + "/n" + "Your new string message here!";
text2.setText(toAppend);
```

Updated:

```
private void setText2Text(String msg) {
    String toAppend = text2.getText();
    toAppend = toAppend + "/n" + msg;
    text2.setText(toAppend);
}
```

Then in your code, replace

```
text2.setText("Your message here")
```

to

```
setText2Text("Your message here")
```

Comment: Did you add the code to all three methods? Or to reduce duplicate code, you can write your own setTextMsg(String msg) method

Comment: i add code to all three method. then i reduce it as you mention before and it still dosn't work

Answer (score 0):

Keep updating the `text` with the appended text using `setText` method itself. Use `getText` to retrieve the existing text and append the new text with the existing text separated by new line.

**Use `System.lineSeparator()` to append the new line in below:**

```
  String text = text2.getText();
  text= text + System.lineSeparator() + "New line text";//<--put the text here
  text2.setText(text);  //<--update the text field value with modified text
```

EDIT:

You are initializing the server inside the thread. Try instantiating it outside and use the same to set the text:

```
 final server myServer = new server();
 /* Create and display the form */
 java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        myServer.setVisible(true);
    }
  });

  JTextArea text1 = myServer.getText1().
  String text = text1.getText();
  text= text + System.lineSeparator() + "New line text";//<--put the text here
  text1.setText(text);  //<--update the text field value with modified text
```

Also define a getter method for `text1` in you class as:

```
  public JTextArea getText1(){
     return this.text1;
  }
```

Comment: @poundPound: Oops. I was having some typos. Corrected now(updated the answer). Check and let me know, if still doesn't work.

Comment: @poundPound I don't see any static context. Can you please point exactly where it is? Any way, it should be working. Is there any issue?

Comment: public static void main(String args[]) throws ISOException {
the first line is the static method and it say you can't reference static method to non static method

Comment: @poundPound Which statement in `main` method gives that error? I know the fix(should be simple), just struggling in getting your issue.

Comment: thankyou so much for reply yogendra.statement give that error is   
text2.setText("Server siap menerima koneksi pada port [" + portNumber+"]");

Comment: @poundPound: Where is the `text2` declaration? I don't see it in the `main` method. **Since `main` is static method, you will not be able to refer any not static resource without instantiation.**

Comment: i don't get it,maybe i really dummy in java

Comment: @poundPound It's fine. I am just asking, where is the declaration of `text2`? Somewhere in in your code you would be having `JTextField text2  ....`. Where is that? If still unclear, share your full code.

Comment: sorry i was made mistake,it's not textfield what i mean but textarea since textfield just put text in one row but it still not work,it's not show in text area

Comment: @poundPound I updated the answer. Can you try and see if its working?

Answer (score 0):

To simulate a console on your GUI, you may need a `JTextPane` because `JTextField` can display only one line of text. You need to create your own way of *"printing out"* to the text pane (You can't use System.out.println to print to GUI).

**Code Sample:**

Assuming you have this as the target:

```
JTextPane guiConsole = new JTextPane();
```

You can create a function like this:

```
private void log(String msg) {
    Document doc = guiConsole.getDocument();
    try {
        doc.insertString(doc.getLength(), msg + "\r\n", null);
    } catch (BadLocationException e) {}
}
```

Now, wherever you would have used `System.out.println("Hello");` to print to the console, just call `log("Hello");` to print the same text to your text pane.

Comment: thanks for answer david,but it not show in textpane.where i declare text pane parameter assuming variable name textpane is txtpane1?

Comment: @poundPound Is your textpane showing? Did you ever call the log method after displaying the gui?

Comment: You did it wrongly. The `JTextPane guiConsole = new JTextPane();` should not be inside the `log` method. It should be declared as a class field. Preferably at the beginning right after you declared `jScrollPane1 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();`. Also, don't forget to add it to your frame, like this `getContentPane().add(guiConsole)`.

Comment: Delete the line that says `JTextPane = new javax.swing.JTextPane();`. It's a compile-time error.

Comment: i can't delete it,it generated by netbbeans

Comment: Ok, change the name of that JTextpane and use that in the log method in place of guiConsole.

Comment: The best advice I can give you is to learn how to write the Swing application by hand rather depending on Netbeans GUI builder. You can search online for a good tutorial.